# how to run insert after update statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run these statements, an insert statement after an update statement:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol='-' WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
INSERT mytable(mycol) VALUES ('hi');
```

but it did not work, only each one separately works, but I need to update some rows and then insert some values and all that sql code in a single sql file, how can achieve that?

thanks

Comment: You can't. updates and inserts have to be separate commands. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here , please explain with examples.

Comment: What's an sql file?

Comment: oh, so, the answer is "You can't. updates and inserts have to be separate commands.", thanks P.Salmon